# Nmap not returning hostnames when connected to 2 networks

Tags: networking, nmap

I've the following configuration : 1 computeur connected a 1 network over Wifi and another network over ethernet. These 2 network are totally independant.

I'm using nmap (6.00)  to check which computer are connected on my wifi network. When I'm connected on the 2 networks I see every computer but nmap is not returning any hostnames. 
But when I only connect to my wifi network (removing the ethernet) nmap is capable to give the hostnames. Do you have any ideas why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research :

`Nmap` uses reverse DNS to get the hostnames (cf [man pages](http://nmap.org/book/man.html))

My ethernet network is providing a DNS, so reverse DNS won't find any name for the IPs since the 2 networks are independant.